# What clubs was Hermione involved in?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, hermione-granger

As there are several clubs like the "Charms Club", etc in Hogwarts, is there a canonical answer for the question: **What clubs was Hermione involved in?**

I was more curious about Hermione, as she was a very keen student and the probability of her, being involved in such club(s) is higher than anyone else in the trio.

**Please mention clubs other than the *Duelling Club***

---

"Charms club" (attended by Vicky Frobisher) was mentioned by Angelina, while she was talking/apologizing to Harry in OotP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are only four club-like entities that we have any indication of Hermione attending:

- The ill-fated Duelling Club, which has to be mentioned
- Dumbledore's Army, though it's not clear to what extent it can really be considered a "club"
- The Society for the Protection of Elvish Welfare (SPEW)<sup>1</sup>. As noted in the extended discussion in comments, it's debatable whether this can really be considered a club; it only ever had one active member (Hermione herself), with Harry and Ron (and Neville, if I recall) basically being bullied into joining. Still, it was *intended* to be a larger movement, so I feel justified in at least giving it a nod
- The Slug Club:

  > "Harry, that's three of my little suppers you've missed now!" said Slughorn, poking him genially in the chest. "It won't do, m'boy, I'm determined to have you! Miss Granger loves them, don't you?"
  >
  > "Yes," said Hermione helplessly, "they're really —"
  >
  > <sup>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* Chapter 12: "Silver and Opals"</sup>

There are, in fact, relatively few "clubs" actually mentioned in the books; in addition to the above, we only hear about:

- Charms club, mentioned in the question
- Gobstones Club:

  > "Does this mean they're going to shut down the Gobstones Club?" one of them asked his friend.
  >
  > <sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 17: "Educational Decree Number Twenty-Four"</sup>

A handful more are mentioned in set dressing for the films, but there's no indication that Hermione attends any of them.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hat-tip to Richard for suggesting this in comments

Comment: Is S.P.E.W. a club?

Comment: @Richard No, it is an organisation. If Hermione organised knitting sessions then it may become a club.

Comment: @Richard "Club" implies multiple people...

Comment: @CHEESE - She had members. Don't forget that Harry and Ron got roped in too...

Comment: @Richard Let me rephrase that: "Club" implies multiple willing members.

Comment: Unless you use a club to make people join?

Comment: @Richard It's kind of an interesting philosophical debate. I'm inclined to agree with CHEESE that it didn't *end up* as a club, because it was basically one member doing stuff and a couple of non-participatory "members by compulsion", but it's worth a mention

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - I'm assuming that in later years Hermione sulked and passive-aggressively withheld sex from Ron unless he agreed to continue acting as Treasurer.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - She managed to badger Neville into buying a badge. Arguably he became a member of this club too, since that was the cost of joining.