# What clubs or school organizations exist in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, hogwarts

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125119/what-clubs-was-hermione-involved-in), what clubs are there in Harry Potter, overall? This includes both school clubs and organizations, as well as clubs for adult wizards.
This includes all media, so film-only clubs are included.

This is separate from the linked question, since it asks for examples from all *Harry Potter* media, as well as not being limited to clubs to which Hermione belongs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What clubs was Hermione involved in?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125119/what-clubs-was-hermione-involved-in)

Comment: @Jonah After referring to books for clubs available in Harry Potter Universe, I was unable to find any club which isn't mentioned in the [answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125121/48898) to your linked question. So I voted to close the question as duplicate

Comment: Astronomy Club, Slug and Bugs Club, chuley cannons fan club, etc.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97265/22917

Comment: I even found a Pottermore club (the fan club of Hans the Augerey). This was not mentioned in the other question. Put another way: My answer to this question couldn't be an answer to the other question, but clearly provides some useful information.

Comment: Ah, it's a movie question. Maybe add the [tag:movie] tag? Not a dupe, but I'm tempted to downvote.

Comment: Plus, there's a club only mentioned on Pottermore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This covers book clubs and movie-only clubs. There are also video-game-exclusive clubs, which are not included.

### [Hans the Augurey Fan Club](http://pottermoreexclusivecontent.tumblr.com/)

> Liechtenstein cause a serious upset in the qualifying stages by
>   winning the group over China, the runners-up in 2010. Liechtenstein’s
>   team mascot is a gloomy, oversized Augurey called Hans who has his own
>   fan club.

I am certain this is, or was, on Pottermore at some point. Curiously, I cannot find the source on Pottermore. There is a "History of the Quidditch World Cup."

### Hogwarts Gobstones Club

Gobstones is a game played with marbles that [squirt foul-smelling liquid.](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gobstones)

> Gobstones is an ancient wizarding game that resembles marbles, the
>   principal difference being that every time a point is conceded, the
>   winning stone squirts a foul-smelling liquid into the loser's face.
>   Players start the game with fifteen small, round Gobstones each
>   (Gobstones are sold in sets of thirty) and the winner must capture all
>   of his opponent’s stones. Though most commonly (as the name implies)
>   made of stone, Gobstones may also be made of precious metals.

Hogwarts apparently has a Gobstones Club

> 'Does this mean they're going to shut down the Gobstones Club?' one of
>   them
>   asked his friend.
>
> 'I reckon you'll be OK with Gobstones,' Ron said darkly, making the
>   second- year jump.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

### Official Gobstone Club

Apparently the Ministry of Magic has a national Gobstones club.

> 'Level Seven, Department of Magical Games and Sports, incorporating
>   the British and Irish Quidditch League Headquarters, Official
>   Gobstones Club and Ludicrous Patents Office.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

### Dueling Club

This was created by Gilderoy Lockhart in an attempt to instruct students in self-defense, prompted by a rash of unexplained attacks.

> Lockhart waved an arm for silence and called “Gather round, gather
>   round! Can everyone see me? Can you all hear me? Excellent!
>
> “Now, Professor Dumbledore has granted me permission to start this
>   little dueling club, to train you all in case you ever need to defend
>   yourselves as I myself have done on countless occasions — for full
>   details, see my published works.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

It was essentially a failure, mainly due to the character of the individual teaching it.

### Dumbledore's Army

This organization was created for the purpose of teaching self-defense, but was much more successful than the dueling club. Harry Potter was the leader, with Hermione Granger as the organizer.

> 'All in favour of the DA?' said Hermione bossily, kneeling up on her
>   cushion to count. That's a majority - motion passed!'
>
> She pinned the piece of parchment with all of their signatures on it
>   on to the wall and wrote across the top in large letters:
>
> DUMBLEDORE'S ARMY
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

### Charms Club

> "Vicky Frobisher and Geoffrey Hooper both flew better this evening, but
>   Hoopers a real whiner, he's always moaning about something or other,
>   and Vicky's involved in all sorts of societies. She admitted herself
>   that if training clashed with her Charms Club she'd put Charms first."
>
> --Angelina Johnson, *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

### Hogwarts Choir

This is a movie-only group.

[image]

### Astronomy Club

[image]
This club was  taught by the Astronomy teacher, Professor Sinistra. This is a movie-only club, known only from a poster in the Gryffindor common room.

### Slug Club

A group of students favored by Professor Slughorn for the advantages they could bring him.

> The afternoon wore on with more anecdotes about illustrious wizards
>   Slughorn had taught, all of whom had been delighted to join what he
>   called the “Slug Club” at Hogwarts. Harry could not wait to leave, but
>   couldn’t see how to do so politely. Finally the train emerged from yet
>   another long misty stretch into a red sunset, and Slughorn looked
>   around, blinking in the twilight.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

### Slugs and Bugs Club

[image]

This is another movie-only club.

### Chudley Cannons Fan Club

[image]

This is a club devoted to the notoriously unlucky Quidditch team the Chudley Cannons. Another film-only club.

[image]

Another club found only in the movies, presumably dedicating to racing rats.

### Art Club for Gryffindor

This club is movie-only, and apparently did drawings of dragons.

[image]

Comment: I cover the missing content from the new Pottermore in [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113605/55866) The article in question is the second of the twenty-seven articles realised for the 2014 QWC, of which only one is on the new Pottermore.

Comment: Good! But is it inaccessible? It certainly seems so.

Comment: @Jonah - All of the old Pottermore is inaccessible. Lots of the content from it were re-released on the new Pottermore, but not all off it. (They needed to make room for what people *really* want, like stupid listicles.) Most of the old content is archived in some form or another online. (I've provided links to lots of it.)

Comment: There is a canonical mention of Chudley Cannon "memorabilia" (in the second Daily Prophet newsletter), but then, that neither implies a club, nor a Hogwarts club.

Comment: What about sports clubs like the quidditch teams?